# (bad-plugin-value) Pylint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I try to create a custom Pylint Module, but I can't load it with Pylint.

```
 pylint test/test.py  --load-plugins pylint_checkers
```

My plugin module ("pylint_checkers") is located at the root of my repo. I am running pylint inside a pipenv.
I got the following error:

```
E0013: Plugin 'pylint_checkers' is impossible to load, is it installed ? ('No module named 'pylint_checkers'') (bad-plugin-value)
```

In my module, I have filled the init file with the following register method:

```py
from pylint_checkers.select_cast_checker import SelectCastChecker


__all__ = ["register"]

def register(linter) -> None:
    """required method to auto register this checker"""
    linter.register_checker(SelectCastChecker(linter))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone will have the same issue. I solved this by adding an init-hook:

```
--init-hook=''import sys; sys.path.append(".")''
```